# limit permissions to certain users

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Hello 2sxc enthusiasts!

I developed a 2sxc application in a protected page. A group of users can read, add and modify the information in that 2sxc application. Since they can do some important actions but not administer the entire page, I gave the rights to "modify the module" (not certain it's the English terms...) to this group of users only for the 2sxc application developed. In my controller, the function attributes are:

```
[HttpPost]
[DnnModuleAuthorize (AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Edit)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

Everything works very well considering the code but giving the editing rights on the DNN module, it appears now the persona bar with this little pencil and no menus that ultimately is useless. This creates an overhead, slowing down the application without need.

I could set the rights to `[DnnModuleAuthorize (AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Annonymous)]` considering the presence of [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and only base the security on the DNN page but is there a way to retain limited rights for the controller without having this persona bar?

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2sxc 9.30 there are new ways to set permissions, incl. at App-level. You could try to remove DNN edit permissions but set the app to editable. We haven't tried this scenario, but it could work.